# Probability To Choose 1 Special Ball Out Of N Balls With K Withdraws

Tags: probability

There are $n$ balls when one of them has a different color.
from the basket we take $k$ balls one after the other (without returning).
All the balls have the same odds to be picked.
what is the probability to choose the ball with the different color?

$P=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}  $ why is the result is $\frac{k}{n}$

Comment: The two answers are the same.

Comment: Apply $\binom{a}{b} = \dfrac{a!}{b! * (a-b)!}$ and do the algebra. You will see $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \dfrac{1}{n}$. The other terms cancel out similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$$

$$P=\frac{\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!}}{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}$$

$$P=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!}\frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}$$

$$P=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}$$

$$P=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}\frac{k!}{n!}$$

$$P=\frac{k}{n}$$